# FireBase onChild Added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding a ".push()" method key on a button click.

Every time i add a "Child" to the parent node it always fetches all the child to that particular node.
Here is the database structure.
[image]

Supposed there are already 5 child nodes under the "plans" parent node.
I will add one more node and all the 5 will be displayed as well and then the 6th one will be displayed too. So total of 11 nodes will be displayed.

I Researched and saw the "Onchildadded" method will work for this just fine but its doing the same thing as the addValueEventListener.

Here is my code for the on addValueEventListener(The initial method I have attached to the onStart of the activity, So anytime a user opens the app it displays all the nodes at that moment in the recyclerview and cardview.

```
 q1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {


                cardViewPlaninfo card = dataSnapshot1.getValue(cardViewPlaninfo.class);






                    listplans .add(card);
                String TAG = "cardTAG";


                cardViewPlaninfo cvpi = new cardViewPlaninfo(card.getUserKEY(),card.getPlanpostedbyname().toString(),card.getCategory().toString(),card.getLocation().toString(),card.getDateandtime().toString(),card.getContribute().toString(),card.getExtranotes().toString());




                cardViewPlaninfolistobj.add(cvpi);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }







        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    super.onStart();

}
```

AND THIS IS the code i'm writing on "Swipe refresh view".

```
void refreshItems()
{
    Query q1 = databaseUsers.child("plans");

    q1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {




            Log.i("OnChildAdded",dataSnapshot.getKey().toString());

                cardViewPlaninfo card = dataSnapshot.getValue(cardViewPlaninfo.class);






                listplans .add(card);
                String TAG = "cardTAG";






                cardViewPlaninfolistobj.add(card);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }




        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




    onItemsLoadComplete();

}

void onItemsLoadComplete()
{


    srl.setRefreshing(false);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So the last idea is that when a user opens the activity "AfterLogin" the onStart() method runs and it shows all the child nodes under the parent node "plans". And When ever another user adds a node that is a child node under the parent node "plans", The other users should be able to swipe and the only child node added is shown with the other 5. So 5 nodes that are already added+ 1 the new node that has been added.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove refreshItems() method from your code it is not needed i have try this code hope this will work for you.

```
Query query = null;
        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Parent Node");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        cardViewPlaninfo card = dataSnapshot.getValue(cardViewPlaninfo.class);
                        mCardViewPlaninfoRecyclerAdapter.add(card);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Log.d("Unable to get message: " + "child changed");
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.d("Unable to get message: " + "child removed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("Unable to get message: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("Unable to get message:", "Unable to get message: ");

            }
        });

        //add this method to your adapter
        public void add(cardViewPlaninfo card) {
                        mCardViewPlaninfoList.add(card);
                        notifyItemInserted(mCardViewPlaninfoList.size() - 1);
                        }
```

Comment: the refreshItems() method is the method to the "swipe refresh layout" and it denotes that when there is a swipe it will refresh. If i remove the refreshItems method, then there is not point of swipe refresh

Comment: I think you have kept swipe to refresh for updating you adapter's data but now there will be no need. if want to keep swipe to refresh you need to clear you adapter data first.

Comment: still it loads all the data twice.

Comment: i use singleValueEventListener to populate the cardviews and the recyclerviews when user "initially" opens the app. And then i use child listeners when a new "node" is added or when the user swipe's to refresh the nodes. I am getting the latest node that is getting added in the "ChildEvenListener" but when i populate the list it actually loads all of them twice